# Unable to commit 'pdf' directory in Subversion

Tags: svn

Tyring to add and commit a 'pdf' directory to subversion(1.9.3) with the following:

```
mkdir pdf

svn add pdf

svn commit -m "adding pdf directory"
```

I then get the following error:

```
Adding         pdf
svn: E175015: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175015: The HTTP method 'MKCOL' is not allowed on '/repos/int/!svn/wrk/5489b72a-9b40-2742-ad1e-fb87a90f4c54/trunk/content/src/main/content/pdf'
```

It is fine for anything other, for example: 'pdfs'.

The 'pdf' directory is not already present in subversion, and have even tried to add it within a newly created subdirectory.

Comment: Do you have any rules in your Apache configuration designed to prevent uploading filenames with `pdf` in them?

Comment: The Apache had a redirect for pdf.  Rule now in place to not redirect a pdf to a repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a redirect for 'pdf' on the Apache server, now configured to not redirect if going to a svn repo.

Thanks to [alroc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324345) for the hint.